# HTTP call - req.url is undefined

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic3

I want to get data from an API link. Api Link and API-key are correct. When I try it with POSTMAN it returns result. When I run the app with http call it gives this error:

**"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: req.url is undefined
HttpXsrfInterceptor.prototype.intercept...**

What is the problem can someone please tell me?

Here is my code.

**App module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
HttpModule ]
})
```

**home.ts**

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class A{
   apiUrl = "yyy-yyy-yyy";
constructor(private http: HttpClient){

   this.getData();
}
getData(){

    let headers =  { headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Accept':  'application/json',
            'user-key': 'xxx-xxx'})}; 

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, headers).subscribe(res=>
                  console.log('RES: ', res));
}
}
```

Error screenshot;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq5RC.png)

Comment: Could you please add your error as text? This makes it easier to read and also easier to find for other people facing the same problem.

Comment: @Yannjoel It is written above: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: req.url is undefined HttpXsrfInterceptor.prototype.intercept...

Comment: And please also include the screenshot, instead of refering it

Comment: @DirkHorsten I have included the screenshot, but unfortunately it is not showing. I dont know why

Comment: Where did you define `this.apiUrl`?

Comment: @JBNizet in the class, above constructor.

Comment: You are not importing `HttpClientModule` at all. Replace `HttpModule` with that.

Comment: @AmitChigadani HttpClientModule is imported in app.module.ts. In home.ts only HttpClient is needed. Without module. As far as i know

Comment: @ProfomStat In your question you show `HttpModule`. Atleast edit that to avoid confusion.

Comment: Are you using http interceptors??

Comment: @SakshamGupta No. I dont even know what they are

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you want to have a service like that:

service.ts

```
constructor(private http: Http
) { }
public mygetdata(): Observable<Data[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('user-key': 'xxx-xxx');

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl), {
        headers: headers
    })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let res = response.json();
            if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
            } else {
                return res.StatusDescription.map(data=> {
                    return new Data(data);
                });
            }
        })
}
```

Component.ts

```
 public data : Data[];

  getdata() {
        this.service.mygetdata().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = data;
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think this pipes and maps all are necessary because they are processes after getting the data. In my case I am not getting the data. Something is wrong with the headers line or headers in http call. If i get the data, then logging it and using it is easy.